# SCSS - Как объединить @media запросы?

Tags: css, scss

Есть такой миксин:

```
/* 
$property - Название свойства
$minValue - MIN размер свойства; 
$maxValue - MAX размер свойства; 
$sizeWidthPage - Минимальная ширина макета(страницы)
*/

@mixin dynamicProperty($property, $minValue, $maxValue, $sizeWidthPage) {
  #{$property}: $maxValue;
  @media (min-width: $sizeWidthPage + px) {
    #{$property}: $minValue + px;
  }
}
```

Вызов миксина:

```
.test1 {
  @include dynamicProperty('font-size', 15, 30, 960);
}
.test2 {
  @include dynamicProperty('width', 20, 25, 960);
}
```

При применении генерируется следующий CSS:

```
.test1 {
  font-size: 30;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .test1 {
    font-size: 15px;
 }
}

.test2 {
  width: 25;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .test2 {
    width: 20px;
 }
}
```

А хотелось бы, чтобы все похожие @media запросы в CSS объединялись так:

```
.test1 {
  font-size: 30;
}
.test2 {
  width: 25;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .test1 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .test2 {
    width: 20px;
  }
}
```

**Возможно ли такое реализовать только синтаксисом SCSS?** Библиотеку для этого загружать особо не хочется.

Comment: В примере перепутал "max-width" с "min-width", но не суть.

Answer (score 0):

На чистом SCSS нет такой возможности.
Только использование сторонних библиотек.

Вот несколько из них:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-mqpacker
https://github.com/aaronjensen/sass-media_query_combiner